# Symfony controller action execution before listener

Tags: php, symfony, listener

Is it possible to have a controller action executed before a listener?

I need to trigger a database change on an action call before a listener checks if this change exists. Can this be set up or even possible in symfony 2/3?

The structure of actions should be like this:

1. ControllerAction saves to database and returns a response
2. Listener checks against the database and execute or redirect based on the end result from the DB

Now the Listener is having priority and I don't know if this is possible to be changed.

Comment: Check `kernel.response` event. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-response-event

Comment: oh, that makes it clear now! thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `kernel.response` event and modify `Response` if needed. http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/http_kernel/introduction.html#the-kernel-response-event